# Karate Framework JSON path parsing using regex not working for the whole word match

Tags: regex, karate, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I am working on matching the name for eg. name in the response says:

'World map'

Now I want to write a generic regex in the karate jsonpath which should work for the word "map" irrespective of its position in the multiple words for eg - One common script should match below permutations.

1 - Climate map 
2 - Wolds map 
3 - Worlds China map 
4 - Big map is too small
5 - Big map is there

What I have written so far, which seems to be not working

```
$..source..[?(@.name =~ /(\bmap\b)/i)]
```

Can anyone please help what exact regex should I put which would check 'map' world in the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is simpler to use pure Java:

```
* def str = 'foo map bar'
* assert str.contains('map')

* def hasMap = function(x){ return x.contains('map') }
* assert hasMap(str)
```

So don't use a regex, please refer this part of the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#self-validation-expressions

Comment: Thanks for your message, but how would I be avoiding the capitalization with your java logic (ignoreUpperCase something like that).

Comment: @vdrulerz `x.toLowerCase().contains('map')`

Comment: @ptrthomas Your solution would only work if you have just one node but when I will parse the response for all nodes in the array it would always pass because of the str.contains

Is there any way that I do this assertion on the arrays for each array object ?

for eg - 

* def getName = get response.source[*].name

now if I print getName it will show

[
"world map",
"state map",
"town map area"
]


Also can we do contains and starts with assertion in one line of code ?

Comment: @vdrulerz please please please read the docs. look for `match each` and then ask a SEPARATE question if needed. thanks